# Is there a way to slow down jest?

Tags: jestjs

I have some tests that pass on my local machine but fail intermittently in CI. I assume it is because the tests run slower in CI.

Is there a way to slowdown the tests on my local machine so that they fail consistently?

Comment: Why not using ``async/await`` (creating ``dummy Promises`` I mean ) so you can drop some delay in each test, is this what your asking about ?

Comment: There are 100's of tests. Ideally I would be looking for flag at the top level.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way based on process priority. Here is a solution for Unix-like systems (for windows you have to find the relevant commands).

First, launch jest in debug mode with a breakpoint at the start, and connect your debugger (chrome devtools in general):
`node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand`

Then find your process id:
`ps -ax | grep node`

Then lower the priority of the process:
`renice -n 20 <pid>`

Resume the jest tests in your debugger.

This should slow down the tests. If it is not enough, I suppose you can try to run some other process on your machine that should take priority.